# Are both "complex float" and "float complex" valid C?

Tags: c

My question is simply this:

> Are both "complex float" and "float complex" valid C?

Both seem to be accepted without warnings by gcc.

Comment: Since `int long unsigned long` is valid, it makes sense for both orders to be valid. I've not formally checked though.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.3.1p4 : *The macro

          `complex`
expands to `_Complex;` the macro
          _`Complex_I`
expands to a constant expression of type `const float _Complex`, with the value of the imaginary unit.*. So `float` is just redundant here.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Using gcc complex on its own defaults to double complex.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `float` is not redundant here. I don't know where you're getting that from.

Comment: @melpomene Ooops. Misread the cited text, sorry.

Comment: Note: As a matter of **style**, the C spec always places `_Complex` last as in `float _Complex`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`complex` is a macro from complex.h which expands into the type specifier `_Complex`. This behaves as all other type specifiers, for example `int, bool, double`. For all type specifiers belonging to the same "group", you can combine them in various orders. This is specified by C11 6.7.2, emphasis mine:

> **At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration
>   specifiers in each declaration**, and in the specifier-qualifier list in
>   each struct declaration and type name. Each list of type specifiers
>   shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when
>   there is more than one multiset per item); **the type specifiers may
>   occur in any order**, possibly intermixed with the other declaration
>   specifiers.

Then follows a list of valid groups of type specifiers, where we find

> - `float _Complex`
> - `double _Complex`

Meaning that any permutation of the specifiers in the same group is fine.

---

To take another example, there is a group

> - `unsigned long long`, or `unsigned long long int`

Which gives us the following possible combinations:

```
unsigned long long x;
long unsigned long y;
long long unsigned z;
```

or

```
unsigned long long int a;
unsigned long int long b;
unsigned int long long c;
int unsigned long long d;
long unsigned long int e;
long long unsigned int f;
long long int unsigned g;
long unsigned int long h;
...
```

These all mean the same thing.

Comment: If you think the above is completely irrational, you are correct. The C language was designed for obfuscation. Sanity was never a priority.

Comment: Or "For language obfuscation C the designed was. Priority sanity was never a".

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In general, the order of "typey words" at the beginning of a declaration doesn't matter:

```
static const unsigned long int x = 42;
```

is the same as

```
long const int unsigned static x = 42;
```

Reference: C99, 6.7.2/2

> [...] the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>   intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

(Both `float` and `_Complex` are type specifiers.)

Comment: N1570 says *"The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration
specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature."*, so using `static` elsewhere than the beginning is a bad idea.

Comment: @user694733 But that only applies to storage-class specifiers. Code like   `static long const int _Atomic long volatile unsigned*const volatile*_Atomic*const x;` is perfectly fine in C...